# controls does not exist when build in prod

Tags: angular

I have an error when I want buid my app in production. Error is :

```
Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

Lines error :

```
userForm.controls['passwords'].controls.repeat_new_password.touched &&
userForm.controls['passwords'].controls.new_password.touched
```

My`controls` :

```
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'email': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      'passwords': new FormGroup({
          'new_password': new FormControl('', [
              Validators.required
          ]),
          'repeat_new_password': new FormControl('', [
              Validators.required
          ])
      }, AddUserComponent.areEqual),
      'selected' : new FormControl('',[
          Validators.required
      ])
  })
```

My `areEqual` control :

```
static areEqual(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(c.value);
    for (const i in keys) {
        if (i !== '0' && c.value[ keys[ +i - 1 ] ] !== c.value[ keys[ i ] ]) {
            return { areEqual: true };
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML :

```
<mat-error class="error-password" *ngIf="
      userForm.controls['passwords'].errors &&
      userForm.controls['passwords'].errors.areEqual &&
      userForm.controls['passwords'].controls.repeat_new_password.touched &&
      userForm.controls['passwords'].controls.new_password.touched
    ">Text error
</mat-error>
```

When I run my app I haven't error. Can you help me ?

Comment: We will need to some of the code [mcve]. It will also help you to debug

Comment: Please [provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) showing what you're attempting to do and where you're stuck. Otherwise, it's pretty much guesswork to know what will actually help you here.

Comment: I have updated my post, sorry

Comment: Try userForm.get('passwords').get('repeat_new_password').touched

Comment: It work thank you :D